# User made Linked List class to store objects in a text file with menu functionality

Tags: java, linked-list, menu

I have been trying to use my own Linked List class (LList) to help store Dwelling objects in a RealEstate Class, which has a linked list of dwelling objects I pull from and store in an associated data file. I am having trouble implementing a menu within the RealEstate class that allows the user to interact with the linked list and as a result make changes to the associated data file. For some reason my program seems to hang on the line when I try to request user input after trying to display my menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class RealEstate2
{
    LList<Dwelling> dList= new LList<Dwelling>();
    int ch;
    FileReader w = null;
    String line1=null;
    String line2=null;
    String line3=null;
    double foot = 0;
    double val = 0;
    String dwellings = null;
    private String fileName;
    //int choice = 1;



    //constructor
    public RealEstate2(String m) throws FileNotFoundException, ListException
    {
        fileName = m;
        //File data = new File(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        try
        {
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
            {
            line1 = sc.nextLine();
            line2 = sc.nextLine();
            line3 = sc.nextLine();
            foot = Double.parseDouble(line2);
            val = Double.parseDouble(line3);
            dList.add(new Dwelling(line1,foot,val));
            }
        }
        catch(ListException a)
                {
                 throw new ListException("fuck");
                }
            sc.close;

        //System.out.println(dList);
    }//end constructor

    public void Manage() throws IOException
        {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Console console = System.console();
        System.out.println("1. Display items");
        System.out.println("2. Add item");
        System.out.println("3. Insert item");
        System.out.println("4. Delete item");
        System.out.println("5. Exit");

        System.out.println("Enter option:");

        int choice = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        //choice = in.nextInt();

        try
        {
        //display
        if (choice == 1)
            System.out.println(this);
        //add
        if (choice == 2)
            System.out.println("Please enter the address:");
            String a = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the square footage:");
            double f = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the value:");
            double v = sc.nextDouble();
            Dwelling x = new Dwelling(a,f,v);
            hList.add(x);
            //
        //insert
        if (choice == 3)
            System.out.println("Please enter the address:");
            String ad = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the square footage:");
            double fo = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the value:");
            double va = sc.nextDouble();
            Dwelling y = new Dwelling(ad,fo,va);
            System.out.println("Please enter the position to insert:");
            int p = sc.nextInt();
            hList.insert(y,p);
        //delete
        if (choice == 4)
            System.out.println("Please enter the position to delete:");
            int d = sc.nextInt();
            hList.delete(d);
        //exit
        if (choice == 5)
            return;

        }
        catch(ListException a)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
 //use update method to update data file

        }//end of manage method














        //tostring

    public void update() throws IOException
        {
            try
            {
            FileWriter d = new FileWriter(fileName);
            dwellings = dList.toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < dwellings.length(); i++)
                d.write(dwellings.charAt(i));
                d.close();
           }
           catch (IOException a)
           {
               throw new IOException();
           }
        }//end of update method


}//end of class
```

```
public class LList<T> //implements ListInterface<T>
{
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private int counter;

    //constructor
    public LList( )
    {
        head=null;
        tail=null;
        counter=0;
    }


    //add method
    public void add( T m ) throws ListException
    {
        try
        {
            Node<T> temp = new Node<T>( );
            temp.setData( m );
            temp.setNext( null );

            if ( head == null)
            {
                head = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                tail.setNext( temp );
            }

            tail = temp;

            counter++;

        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            throw new ListException("Cannot add. No more memory");
        }
    }

    //delete method
    public T delete(int position) throws ListException
    {
        Node<T> current=head;
        Node<T> before=null;

        T temp;

        if ( counter == 0 )
            throw new ListException("Cannot delete. List is empty.");

        if ( position >= 1 && position <= counter )
        {
            //the position is valid
            if (counter == 1 ) //is there only 1 node
            {
                temp = head.getData();
                head=null;
                tail=null;
                counter--;
                return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                //there are at least 2 nodes
                if ( position == 1 )
                {
                    //there are at least 2 nodes and the user is trying to delete the first node
                    temp = head.getData();
                    head = head.getNext();
                    counter--;
                    return temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    //there are at least 2 nodes but the user is not trying to delete the first
                    int k = 1;

                    while (k != position )
                    {
                        before = current;
                        current = current.getNext();
                        k++;
                    }
                    //we have arrived at the node to be deleted
                    temp = current.getData();
                    before.setNext( current.getNext() ); //gets rid of desired node

                    //Did we just delete last node
                    if ( before.getNext() == null )
                        tail=before;
                    counter--;
                    return temp;

                }


            }
        }
        else
        {
            //the position is invalid
            throw new ListException("Cannot delete. Position is bad.");
        }





    }//end of delete method

    //tostring method
    public String toString()
    {
        if (head == null )
        {
            return "The list is empty.";
        }
        String t = "";
        Node<T> temp;
        temp=head;
        while ( temp != null )
        {
            t += temp.getData() + "\n";

            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return t;
    }//end of toString

    //insert method
    public void insert( T item, int position ) throws ListException
    {
        try
        {
            if (counter == 0 )
                throw new ListException("Cannot insert. List is empty.");

            if (item == null )
                throw new ListException("Cannot insert. Item is invalid.");

            if (position <1 || position > counter )
                throw new ListException("Cannot insert. Position is bad.");

            Node<T> temp = new Node<T>();
            temp.setData( item );

            if (position == 1)
            {
                temp.setNext( head );
                head = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T> before = head;
                Node<T> current = head;
                int k=1;
                while( k != position )
                {
                    before = current;
                    current = current.getNext();
                    k++;
                }

                temp.setNext( current );
                before.setNext( temp );
            }
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
        {
            throw new ListException("Cannot insert. No more memory.");
        }
    }//end of insert method

    public int Size( )
    {
        return counter;
    }
} //end of LList
```

```
public class Node<T>
{
    private T data;
    private Node<T> next;

    //default constructor
    public Node()
    {
        data = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public void setData( T  p )
    {
        data = p;

    }

    public T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setNext( Node<T> n)
    {
        next = n;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }

} //end of the class
```

```
public class Dwelling
{
    private String address;
    private double footage;
    private double value;

    //constructor
    Dwelling(String add, double f, double v) throws ListException
    {
        if (add == null || add.length() == 0)
                {
                    throw new ListException("The address cannot be null");
                }
                else
                {
                    this.address = add;
                }
        if(f <= 100)
                    {
                        throw new ListException("The squarefootage cannot be less then 100 ft.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.footage = f;
                    }
        if(v <= 100000)
                    {
                        throw new ListException("The value cannot be less then $100000.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.value = v;
                    }
    }


      // Getter
      public String getAddress()
      {
        return address;
      }

      // Setter
      public void setAddress(String newAddress) throws ListException
      {
        if (newAddress == null || newAddress.length() == 0)
        {
            throw new ListException("The address cannot be null");
        }
        else
        {
            this.address = newAddress;
        }

      }

      // Getter
      public double getFootage()
      {
        return this.footage;
      }

      // Setter
      public void setFootage(double foot) throws ListException
      {
          if(foot <= 100)
            {
                throw new ListException("The squarefootage cannot be less then 100 ft.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.footage = foot;
            }

      }

    // Getter
      public double getValue()
      {
      return this.value;
      }

  // Setter
      public void setValue(double val) throws ListException
      {
            if(val <= 100000)
                {
                    throw new ListException("The value cannot be less then $100000.");
                }
            else
                {
                     this.value = val;
                }




      }

      //toString
      public String toString()
      {
            return address + "\n" + footage + "\n" + value + "\n";
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if blocks are missing the closing brackets {} around them. Always place a bracket even if the if block has only one line for clarity.
Also, that if block should really be a switch block, but remember to always add a break for each of the choices in the switch.

You're declaring Scanner sc in the constructor and trying to use it on the Manage method, I'm not sure how that compiles.
In the Manage method you declare a Scanner in, you probably should use that scanner variable to scan values in your menu choices.
Also, for some reason you're using

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
```

to read the user choice, you should use Scanner in instead.

```
int choice = in.nextInt();
```

Edit: here are your if blocks rewritten:

```
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println(this);
            break;

        //add
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please enter the address:");
            String a = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the square footage:");
            double f = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the value:");
            double v = in.nextDouble();
            Dwelling x = new Dwelling(a, f, v);
            hList.add(x);
            break;
        //
        //insert
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Please enter the address:");
            String ad = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the square footage:");
            double fo = in.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Please enter the value:");
            double va = in.nextDouble();
            Dwelling y = new Dwelling(ad, fo, va);
            System.out.println("Please enter the position to insert:");
            int p = sc.nextInt();
            hList.insert(y, p);
            break;

        //delete
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Please enter the position to delete:");
            int d = in.nextInt();
            hList.delete(d);
            break;

        //exit
        case 5:
            return;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the help, sorry I know there is a bunch of incomplete and junk code lying. I have been alternating between the scanner nextInt and console parseInt because when I use the scanner the program just hangs where when using the console I instead get a null pointer exception.

Comment: I have made the changes you recommended but still have an issue where my program hangs when the in.nextInt() line is included. Any idea why that line would be giving me an issue?

Comment: is it possible it's not hanging but rather waiting for your input?

Comment: not to my knowledge, attempting to enter any input yields an "Interrupted!" exit code